# Using onClickListener to show clicked image in larger size in another layout or activity?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm supporting an android 2.2+ app. I'm using the code `image.setOnClickListener(new View.On Click Listener()`
and a dialog to show a larger image in another layout.

Current project has an error. When I debug the project, I see a `NullPointerException` on `image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()` saying the image is null.

### Main Activity

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    Context c;
    Intent intent;
    ImageView image, image1;

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        image = (ImageView) image.findViewById(R.id.image_my);

        // *** mean here

        image_my.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TO DO Auto-generated method stub
                show(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void show(View v) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.show);
        image1 = (ImageView) image1.findViewById(R.id.image_my1);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

### Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_my1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/image_def" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger and checking where you expect the image value to be set?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got this code from, but you are repeatedly using variables before you have assigned them:

```
image = (ImageView) image.findViewById(R.id.image_my);
```

Here you are calling `findViewById` on your `image` instance, but `image` will be `null` here. You probably want:

```
image = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image_my);
```

Similarly, in your `show()` method:

```
image1 = (ImageView) image1.findViewById(R.id.image_my1);
```

should be

```
image1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image_my1);
```

You might want to try using more descriptive names for your variables too - it makes it a bit easier to spot problems like this.

Comment: thanks.not work. this cod correct in new project  . i  have 250 pic in my project.how i can click in pick and big size like whats app?